# Using webcam to track hand gestures

Tags: algorithm, gesture-recognition, gesture

I wanted to develop a program which uses the webcam to track four colours and which are going to be on my index finger and thumb of both my hands and according to the gestures of my hand the computer will interpret these gestures and carry out a command. For example if I have a website open, all I have to do is pinch with my fingers and the webpage will zoom. I wanted the advice of the stackoverflow community as to where to start and whether anyone has any advice for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is something I've considered trying to do, very neat idea but I have a feeling it's much harder than it would seem.

Comment: @Earlz.Have you seen the sixth sense thing? http://www.ted.com/talks/view/id/685

Comment: no, but I have it bookmarked now

Comment: @Earlz Let me know wht you think

Answer (score 4):

You could look at Johnny Chung Lee's work with the Wii Remote:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0awjPUkBXOU

You could base your code off the Wiimote library:

http://www.codeplex.com/WiimoteLib

Another angle might be the Aforge Library:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx

Code: http://code.google.com/p/aforge/

Answer (score 2):

Something really similar already exists:

http://incubator.quasimondo.com/flash/minority_cube.php

Comment: Do you think i could use a flash decompiler to get the code out of it?

Comment: you might could try contacting the author and seeing if he would give you a private copy of just the actionscript code....

Answer (score 1):

You will certainly want to use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) in one form or another.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at OpenCV, search OpenCV Gesture recognition

Answer (score 0):

I think, by using the motion tracking in openCV examples, it is possible to achieve similar effects as the minority cube demonstrated.