# How does Flash ActionScript read hand gesture using webcam?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, webcam, gesture

So sorry that I'm so very newbie, and have googled only to find the same result again and again, till desperately I decided to ask here...

So, I need to make a webpage that can detect/reading hand gesture. At first, I was so very lost in what to do, but then this and that, I've found these questions:

- [Using webcam to track hand gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275843/using-webcam-to-track-hand-gestures)
- [Generating events for gesture-controlled websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008087/generating-events-for-gesture-controlled-websites)
- [How to detect hand gesture in live webcam using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227464/how-to-detect-hand-gesture-in-live-webcam-using-javascript)
- [hand gesture recognition with camera video in actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529118/hand-gesture-recognition-with-camera-video-in-actionscript)

And after surfed things I found there, then I (thought that I) got that it could be done using Javascript or Flash ActionSript, and have seen some of the examples for both. While I (thought that I) understood that people did it through Javascript by implementing algorithm for image processing and its friends, actually I'm kinda lost at how Flash did that. I found the common usage of gesture using Flash is in 'webcam game', and then I found these tutorial:

- [Webcam Motion Detection: Using the BitmapData API in Flash 8](http://www.adobe.com/mena_fr/devnet/flash/articles/webcam_motion.html)
- [Np's Webcam Game Tutorial](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/364528)

While I (thought that I) kinda get how the first one did it, I'm lost at how the second working out his collision detection... And I don't really understand why, while mostly the Javascript I found has pretty good documentation, so hard to find something like that for Flash ActionScript, and the one I found is kinda old (the first tutorial said it's created at 2005, and the second uploaded in 2007). I would just use Javascript because of those things, but then this [Incubator Quasimondo Minority Cube](http://incubator.quasimondo.com/flash/minority_cube.php) is really cool, and I haven't found an implementation in that level for Javascript...
Thus all of it leads me to a question, roughly:

- how hand gesture detection usually implemented in Flash? like, in webcame games?
- does those implementation really 'recognize' it's a hand? or does it just execute anything that moves?
- what support Flash/ActionScript have for detecting gesture? Like [Camera.activityLevel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000863.html) property, is there another property or library?

I'm so sorry for my lack of knowledge...

Answer (score 0):

All the examples I've seen are simply using the 'image recognition method'. Thus the results are not solid and sometimes there won't be anything to detect at all. That's why Eugene created augmented reality [framework](http://www.augmented-reality-games.com/), but you need a marker in order to use it. He did some experiments without markers, but I cannot find any of them now, sorry.

I've used Kinect for gestures and it works pretty well, and it has AIR sdk.. Maybe you should give it a try :)

Comment: First, thank you so very much for your answer and suggestion :) But I'm so sorry, for now, I think it has been out of the scope I've chosen for this project. Thank you so much for the information though, I learn something new and very interesting! :)